# What's the effect of this kind of layout?

Tags: pcb, layout

In this PCB layout, the designer connects the DC+ pins (high voltage around 300V after the bridge diode rectifier) with a large copper region but contains some folding parts on the way (the area which I highlighted). I've seen some professional designs with this kind of polygon connect. Could anyone point out what's the effect of this kind of layout compared to the direct polygon connect ? [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "folding parts"?

Comment: It's the blue highlighted area in the picture

Comment: But what's "folding" about that? I'm trying to understand where you're coming from so I (or another reader) can give you a good answer.

Comment: I mean, the polygon pour is normally direct and straight, but in this picture, there are some strange zigzags (or corners) in the polygon pour, which is the blue highlighted area. My question is that what's the purpose of the designer while drawing this and how it can improve the quality of layout ?

Comment: It routes current from the bridge into the reservoir cap instead of past it into the circuit under power. By increasing impedance to the pulsed current, I'd expect a marginal effect on ripple seen by the circuit being powered.